# join three tables or use nested queries with IN

Tags: mysql, sql

**(a)** List the names of the cities (from table City) whose name starts with 'p' and are in France (from table Country.

**(b)** List all columns from the Patient table for the patient's whose email contains '@gmail.com' and are from Atlanta

I have tried to join these tables but I do not seem know which values to join together

```
select city_name, email, first_name, last_name, pid, title, address_id, gender
from City c  join Patient p on c.city_name = p.address_id
where p.email like '@gmail.com%'and c.city_name like 'Atlanta%
```

The result is supposed to show cities in France that start with 'p' and patients within a table whose email contains @gmail.com and that live in Atlanta.

Comment: It should be `email like '%@gmail.com'`, not `email like '@gmail.com%'`

Comment: And why do you need to use `LIKE` with the city name? Shouldn't it be an exact match?

Comment: ok so i made the changes and the results for the table are still blank. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: SELECT country_name.Country, email.Patient, city_name.City,
FROM Country, Patient, City
WHERE country_name.Country = "France",
AND city_name.City LIKE "p",
AND email.Patient LIKE "@gmail.com"

Comment: I am almost certain that `c.city_name = p.address_id` is the wrong column to join.

Comment: The City table contains city_name, city_id & country_id The Country table contains country_id & country_name The Patient table contains pid int(50) 
first_name varchar(50) 
last_name varchar(50) 
title varchar(50) 
address_id int(50) 
email varchar(50) 
gender varchar(50)

Comment: should the patient table don't also have a city_id and country_id? or is that in the address table?

Comment: no the patient table does not have city or country id that is in the address table

Answer (score 1):

You should not link the city name with the address id (`c.city_name = p.address_id`). Similar fields (usually primary and foreign keys) that contain the same structure (type, length, etc.) should be linked.

Since you are using the address ID, the address table must also be added as it contains the city ID. Regarding email search, "contains" means that it may be in the middle, so you must allow any characters at the beginning as well.

Try something like this:

```
select 
c.city_name, p.email, p.first_name, p.last_name, pid, title, p.address_id, p.gender
from Patient as p 
join Address as a on p.address_id = a.address_id
join City as c on c.city_id = a.city_id
where p.email like '%@gmail.com%'
  and c.city_name = 'Atlanta'
```